# Freemarker Trailing zeroes after decimal point

Tags: java, freemarker, number-formatting, velocity

I am converting Velocity template to Freemarker template. I'd like to display a `double` value as-is for values having 0 after decimal point, for ex. I have value `1.0` ; in Freemarker it is displaying just `1`. Whereas Velocity template displays `1.0`

I have values in the list as `1.0` `1.001` `4.0` `6.345`
Values having some decimal values like `1.001` `6.345` is getting displayed as-is because there is some value after decimal point. But `1.0` and `4.0` is displayed as `1` and `4`. How to display values `1.0` `4.0` in Freemarker ?

I tried  `?string[...]` but it did not work. Also, exact number of trailing zeroes is unknown.

Comment: I guess Velocity simply `toString()`-s the numbers. There's no built-in for that. But `1`, and `1.0` are exactly the same anyway, except for most programming languages. Are you generating source code?

Comment: This is a cost value from Java. In Velocity getting this cost value using ```$cost()``` and not using ```toString()```. While in Freemarker I used ```${cost()}``` to get cost value.

Comment: What I'm saying is that Velocity internally probably uses `toString()` to convert the number to `String`. I'm not sure, but what you show looks like that. `toString()` is not useful, unless you are generating source code. Like it will not consider the locale.

Comment: Anyway, doesn't a number format like `0.0#####` give what you need? Not sure how many digits are needed in the particular application, but `double` can only store with around 18 significant digits precision anyway.